# How to create feedburner feed for sub-folder?

Tags: wordpress, feedburner

I have a website http://www.bccfalna.com/ where I will talk about computer technology. I have settled up this site with WordPress CMS. I have installed two other WP blogs on the same domain in sub-folders.

The first sub-folder is related to Question-Answer theme at www.bccfalna.com/question-answer/ where any user can place a Question and other user can make an Answer to that question like StackOverflow is doing.

I want that when someone posts a Question, all registered user (Registered with FeedBurner Email Subscription) be informed with the Latest Question through EMail. Since FeedBurner will send email to all the registered users, there is no problem for me but I am not able to Burn a feed for WP installed on a particular sub-folder.

I mean, I want to create a separate FeedBurner Feed for each WP installed in a Sub-Folder. How can I fullfill this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) which will let you mash two or more feeds into one. Than use that output in Feedburner to capture the combined feeds.